# SQL Server: Read data from URL Text File

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am looking for a way to read a data from URL and store it in a Table or a variable in SQL Server.

http://10.10.1.10/data/data.txt

The data in this URL will be like this **746473**

The URL will have only one data at any point of time

Is it possible to capture this and store it against a variable or to a table. For guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but do you really want to open database in a such way?

Just read the data using another language like node.js or C# and call the T-SQL code then.

You can use use [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15) for such task or use some kind of [CLR](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-service-from-sql-server-using-c-sharp-sql-clr/) component.  It's more complicated for sure then reading the data with node.js and inserting into a database.

I am advising to reconsider.